# Python Toolbox - Parameters drop down list will not update with new parameter

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I am making a python toolbox for ArcGIS Pro 2.9.8 with arcpy in Python 3.7
I have a workspace parameter defined as

```
param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Feature Dataset or Geodatabase containing featureclasses",
        name="in_fcs",
        datatype="DEWorkspace",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input", )
```

Parameter 3 this the input field name; all the featureclasses should have the same fields with the same meaning so I just want to return a list of fields based on the first featureclass in the input workspace which is accomplished with this

```
param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Weight Field",
        name="weightField",
        datatype="GPString",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input", )
```

and...

```
    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        if not parameters[1].altered:
            parameters[3].filter.list = None
            parameters[3].value = None
        elif parameters[1].altered and not parameters[1].hasBeenValidated:
            parameters[3].filter.type = "ValueList"
            parameters[3].filter.list = [i.name for i in 
            arcpy.ListFields(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(parameters[1].value)[0])]
            parameters[3].value = parameters[3].filter.list[0]
```

This works, when I add a Workspace in the tool it gives me a dropdown list of the fields of the first featureclass but it doesn't update when I change the Workspace to something else with different featureclasses and I'm not sure why. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With some help from a colleague we discovered that it is not recommended to use arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() or arcpy.ListFields() in a pythonToolBox and that the Describe method is prefered. My first solution was to simply add arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[1].value but I didn't like this. With some help I came up with the following code works.

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    if not parameters[1].altered:
        parameters[3].filter.list = None
        parameters[3].value = None
    elif parameters[1].altered and not parameters[1].hasBeenValidated:
        parameters[3].filter.type = "ValueList"
        parameters[3].filter.list = [i.name for i in arcpy.Describe(parameters[1].value).children[0].fields]
        parameters[3].value = parameters[3].filter.list[0]
```

I'm moving forward with this but if you have a better answer, perhaps something cleaner let me know.